# Remove apps from upper menu bar permanently

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, dock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide system tray icons on OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/216938/hide-system-tray-icons-on-os-x)

Hi, I have an iMac with Leopard 10.6.6 and I'd like to remove some app from upper menu bar permanently, but I don't know how to do it.

Sometimes, when I install new software the start automatically there like Plex or Mobile Mouse Server, but I need them only in some occasion.

I've seen online some guide talks about holding <kbd>CMD</kbd> key and drag the app icon outside the bar, but doing it opens the context menu of the app.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Related: [this](http://superuser.com/questions/217649/show-hide-application-icon-in-dock/217698#217698).

Comment: OK, now I understand. See the linked answer.